# VBA: Copying cells until empty cell is found 1004

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy the values from column E from Workbook IID.xlsm until an empty cell is found. And paste them into Placeholder.xlsm column A.

I have the following code but I get an error on the third line

```
Dim cnt As Long 'add this to your declarations area
With Workbooks("IID.xls").Sheets("Outage Request List")
    cnt = .Range("A5", .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Rows.Count
    Workbooks("Placeholder.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E5").Resize(cnt).Value = _
    .Range("A5", .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Value
End With
```

Error 1004: Application defined error or object-defined error

Comment: You are trying to assign a two column range of values to 1 column.  do you want both columns or just 1.

Comment: But the error comes because you are missing `.` before `Cells(Rows...` on the second to the last line.

Comment: Just 1 column. Added the '.' but still getting the same error. @ScottCraner

Comment: can you [edit] the code above to show the change?

Comment: edit @ScottCraner

Comment: On which line is the error occurring?

Comment: @Gary'sStudent  cnt = .Range("A5", .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Rows.Count

Comment: Then try:  ***cnt = Range(.Cells(5,1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Rows.Count***

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I still get the same error.

Comment: If `Workbooks("IID.xls")` is not the active workbook, and the actual active workbook is a `.xlsx`/`.xlsm` then `.Range("A5", .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Rows.Count` will error.  This is because `Rows.Count` (inside the `.Cells(...)` ) will return the row count of the active sheet = 1048576, which is greater then the rows on a `.xls` causing an invalid range reference.  To fix it, change to `.Rows.Count`